# How to access the fields in WPForms custom action?

Tags: forms

I have a form with one text field Phone Number.
I want to perform a custom action with this field. How do I access the submitted field in this code?

```
function wpf_custom_form_action( $action, $form_data) {  

 if ( $form_data[ 'id' ] == '168' ) {
 
     return "somesite.com";
    
 
    }
 
    return $action;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would likely be available in one of the function parameters (most likely `$form_data`), or the global `$_POST` variable.

Comment: I tried `$_POST[0]` but it was empty

Comment: It's unlikely the array would have numerical keys. Try `var_dump( $_POST )` to see if there's data there. If not, then try dumping the function parameters to see what's in there.

Comment: Thank you so much. This gives me hope. The var_dump result is:
```array(1) { [“wpforms”]=> array(6) { [“author”]=> string(1) “2” [“post_id”]=> string(1) “2” [“submit”]=> string(14) “wpforms-submit” [“token”]=> string(32) “6fa83de7b7c61abfa5c22d20e80348f3” [“complete”]=> array(1) { [2]=> array(4) { [“name”]=> string(12) “Phone Number” [“value”]=> string(4) “9123” [“id”]=> int(2) [“type”]=> string(4) “text” } } [“entry_id”]=> int(0) } }```

Comment: Yep, that looks like it contains submitted form data. You're welcome. Please mark this answer as accepted if you are able.

Comment: I have marked it as answer. Please it will be very helpful if you can show how exactly I can access the phone number field? I see that it is sent as name. I tried ```$_POST['name']``` and ```$_POST['4']['name']```. Both are empty.

Comment: Looks like the offsets would be this: `$_POST['wpforms']['complete'][2]['value']`. I recommend checking the function parameters though: the same data may be there in an easier structure.